# How is this dual function derived?

Tags: optimization, proof-explanation, discrete-optimization, non-convex-optimization, binary-programming

Say we have primal problem:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & c^T x\\ \text{subject to} & Ax \le b\\ & x_i (1-x_i) = 0, \quad i \in [n]\end{array}$$

where $\le$ means component-wise greater than or equal to. The Lagrangian is

$$L(x, \mu, v) = - b^T\mu + (c+A^T\mu-v)^Tx- x^T \text{diag}(v)x$$

Minimizing over $x$ gives the dual function we get

$$g(\mu, v) = -b^T\mu - (1/4)\sum_{i=1}^n(c_i+a_i^T - v_i)^T/v_i$$

if $v \ge 0$ and $-\infty$ otherwise.  $a_i$ is the $i$th column of $A$.

**Can someone explain how this dual function is derived?  I don't see how to show it's this expression.**

Taking the gradient of $L$ should be $-2*\text{diag}(v)x + (c+A^T\mu - v) = 0$

Which implies $x^* = (-1/2)\text{diag}(v)^{-1}(c + A^T\mu - v)$

But substituting this into $L$ doesn't give this result.

Comment: Should the Lagrangian be $+x^T\mathrm{diag}(\nu)x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach looks good. If we let $N:=\mathrm{diag}(\nu)$, then the Lagrangian is
$$
\mathcal{L}(x,\mu,\nu)=-\mu^Tb+(c+A^T\mu-\nu)^Tx+x^TNx
$$
as you suggest. If $\nu>0$ then this expression has the unique minimizer $x^*$ given by
$$
x^*=-\tfrac{1}{2}N^{-1}(c+A^T\mu-\nu)
$$
Plugging this back into the Lagrangian, I get
$$
\mathcal{L}(x^*,\mu,\nu)=-\mu^Tb-\tfrac{1}{4}(c+A^T\mu-\nu)N^{-1}(c+A^T\mu-\nu),
$$
which, written in component form, is equal to
$$
\mathcal{L}(x^*,\mu,\nu)=g(\mu,\nu)=-\mu^Tb-\tfrac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\nu_i}\cdot(c_i+a_i^T\mu-\nu_i)^2.
$$
This is the answer you suggest, assuming that $a_i\mapsto a_i^T\mu$ and the outer transpose should be a $2$.

Comment: How did you get $+x^TNx$?  Isn't a Lagrangian supposed to be $f_0 + \mu^Tf + v^T g?$

Comment: Yes, but $g_i(x)=0$ is the same as $-g_i(x)=0$. So I replaced $x_i(1-x_i)=0$ with $-x_i(1-x_i)=x_i^2-x_i=0$. When you take the inner product of the vectorized version of this with $\nu$ you get $\sum_i-\nu_ix_i+\nu_ix_i^2$.

Comment: Shouldn't the Lagrangian also have $b^T\mu$ added in?

Comment: Yes it does--I dropped a plus sign! See edited version

Comment: And not to keep nitpicking but I just want to make sure I'm understanding: Should the $x$ in $x^*$ be $c$?

Comment: Not nitpicking! Easy to make mistakes when typing these things up. Indeed it should be a $c$

Comment: Ah, I completely forgot that the entries of $N^{-1}$ were $1/v_i$.  Thank you, that answers the question.